# Double if breaks url

Tags: nginx

We have following config:

```
location / {
    #This statement adding extra slash to url 
    if ($http_cookie !~ 'skip_geo=yes') {
       set $allow_visit "${allow_visit}_at_all";
    }


    if ($allow_visit = no_at_all) {
       rewrite ^ http://domain/block.html;
    }

    proxy_pass http://backend/;
}
```

Why extra slash is added?

Config can be fixed by removing slash from `proxy_pass`, but whole story looks unstable.

Comment: I can't understand what extra slash are talking? And, BTW, http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I know, that if is evil. However, in some cases it is fast temporary solution. If we comment first if statement - slash magically disappear.